# ¿Cómo validar el filtro de datos de dos Textbox?

Tags: c#

Hago un filtro de fechas utilizando dos *Textbox* donde el txt1 es el filtro de una fecha de inicio y txt2 es el filtro de una fecha final, eso lo hace bien, o que necesito es validar que la fecha que se inserte en el txt1 sea menor a la fecha insertada en el txt2 y que si el txt2 es menor que la fecha del txt1 me mande un mensaje de error espero pueda ayudarme.

este es el codigo que utilizo para el filtro:

```
da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT on (fecha_y_hora,nombre_y_apellidos ) fecha_y_hora FROM reportes WHERE fecha_y_hora BETWEEN'" + txt1.Text + "'AND'" + txt2.Text + "'", cn);

                ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "ProyectoAsistenciaCCB");
                dgvMostrar.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @karol, pregunta, ¿Cuál es el objetivo de tomar unas fechas con tipo `TextBox`? De igual forma, ¿Cuál es el formato de fechas que manejas en esas cajas de texto? ¿No sería mejor poner un `DateTimePicker`? Tendrías la ventaja de que por default te toma el valor de tipo `DateTime` y ya con eso es más fácil la comparación de fechas :)

Comment: am ok y utilizando dos DateTimePicker como seria la validación?

Answer (score 2):

Usando `DateTimePicker`, tiene un evento llamado `ValueChanged`, ahí es donde tienes que validar que el inicio no sea mayor al final o el final menor al mayor

```
 private void dateTimePicker3_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dateTimePicker3.Value > dateTimePicker4.Value)
        {
            dateTimePicker4.Value = dateTimePicker3.Value;
        }
    }

    private void dateTimePicker4_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dateTimePicker4.Value < dateTimePicker3.Value)
        {
            dateTimePicker3.Value = dateTimePicker4.Value;
        }
    }
```

Si la fecha inicial es mayor a la final o al revés, se va a poner la misma fecha en ambos controles.

Answer (score 2):

Para comparar 2 fechas tienes el método Compare de la clase DateTime, el cual se usa así:

```
DateTIme fecha_1 = DateTime.Parse(txt1.Text);
DateTIme fecha_2 = DateTime.Parse(txt2.Text);

int res = DateTime.Compare(fecha_1, fecha_2);
if(res == -1)
{
    //Fecha 2 es mayor que fecha 1
}else if(res == 0)
{
    //Las 2 fechas son iguales
}else
{
    //Fecha 2 es menor que fecha 1
    MessageBox.Show("Error, fecha 2 es menor que fecha 1", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Aquí tienes la documentación de ese método: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

*Si deseas que esta condición se realice al presionarse el botón **Buscar*** puedes hacerlo así:

```
private void btnComenzar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Variables de tipo fecha.
    // Debes convertir las fechas "que están en los TextBox"
    // en valores de tipo DateTIme.
    DateTIme fecha_1 = DateTime.Parse(txt1.Text);
    DateTIme fecha_2 = DateTime.Parse(txt2.Text);   

    if (fecha_1 > fecha_2) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("La fecha #1 no puede ser mayor a la fecha #2", "Titulo del mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else 
    {
        if (fecha_2 < fecha_1) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("La fecha #2 no puede ser menor a la fecha #1", "Titulo del mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Agrega aquí el resto de tu código.
        }
    }
}
```